# Cox proportional hazards and age of diagnosis

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, age

I'm trying to understand factors that are associated with age of diagnosis of a condition "X". This has been done in a retrospective cross-sectional study, where people are recruited if they have been diagnosed with "X". So, naturally, everyone has a diagnosis of "X" and everyone has been recruited after they have been diagnosed with "X".

There is also participation bias. The participant's likelihood of registering to participate in the study decreases with time after diagnosis. So older participants in the study are more likely to be diagnosed older than when they were younger.

Keeping this in mind, is it pertinent to use age of diagnosis as time and run cox regression? This is an example formula:

```
coxph(Surv(diagnosis_age, event) ~ Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor3 + sex + age_at_registration, data = data1)
```

Note, coxzph test identifies significant associations with some of the covariates (e.g, age_at_registration and sex) violating the proportional hazards assumption.

An alternative model is to use log of diagnosis age and conduct a linear regression:

```
lm(log(diagnosis_age + 1) ~ Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor3 + sex + age_at_registration, data = data1)
```

However, I'm uncertain if this is statistically appropriate.

Comment: One of the main advantages of Cox PH (and of survival analysis more generally) is that it deals well with censoring.  But you haven't got any censoring.